Vuetify v-data-table sort on string formatted dates and potential nulls
I have a v-data-table which includes dates that have been formatted with dayjs to "MM/DD/YYYY" however some dates are null since they have not been completed yet. I am trying to add sorting in the header array for this formatted date column by:
        { title: 'Memo Date', key: 'memo_date', align: 'center', visible: true, filtered: [], sort: 
      function(a: string, b: string) {
        if (a == null && b == null) 
        {
          let c = dayjs().format("MM/DD/YYYY")
          console.log(c)

          return 0
        }
        else if (a == null) {
          let c = dayjs().format("MM/DD/YYYY")
          console.log(c)
          return (dayjs(c).diff(dayjs(b)))
        } else if (b == null) 
        {
          let c = dayjs().format("MM/DD/YYY")
          console.log(c)
          return (dayjs(a).diff(dayjs(c)))
        }
        return dayjs(a).diff(dayjs(b))
      }
    },

However, the ordering does not seem to put these null dates as the most recent date to sort ahead of the actually dates. For instance, if the date is null i try to convert it to today so it is ordered as the newest item but this does not seem to work as expected.
UPDATE:
Based on the recent answer I have posted a potential usage for sorting but still the null dates are showing up as earlier dates whereas I want those to be considered the newest dates:
const customDateSort = (a : string, b : string) => {
  const aDate = String((new Date(a)).getTime())
  const bDate = String((new Date(b)).getTime())
  return aDate.localeCompare(bDate)
}


Why no convert it to a timestamp?

How would it compare it? Can you provide what you are referring to in an answer?

You can improve this question by listing just the comparison function in isolation and a small sample set to demo the issue.

Filter your first dates to remove the null ones. With something like dates.filter(date -> !date) You could also 2 different arrays: one with the null dates and one with the populated dates.

The issue with filtering is these nulls still need to show the empty dates in the v-data-table. The sort in the v-data-table header sorts off the items array.

Wait, you said that some dates are null but you can put the current date in place? Why not use this then? You travel the new array with .map or else, you spot the null values, replace them with new Date().getTime(), then sort them based on their timestamp. Null ones will be the current time, hence the higher number of all, and sorted accordingly. The easiest way and also decently clean.

This may be a problem with how the comparator function works. It seems that you are also trying to sort dates in descending order by default as well which can be a bit confusing to put into code.
take for example
(today: dayjs, yesterday: dayjs) => {
  return today.diff(yesterday)
}

today.diff(yesterday) will return a positive integer, which sorts today after yesterday (yesterday is on top)
To solve this, I think you should try reversing your .diff() order:
function(a: string, b: string) {
    let today = dayjs()
    console.log(c)

    if (a == null && b == null) 
    {
      return 0
    }
    else if (a == null) {
      // "a" is null, so we should return
      // a negative value by diffing a past date with a future day
      return (dayjs(b).diff(today))
    } else if (b == null) 
    {
      // the reverse of above, return a positive value
      return (today.diff(dayjs(a)))
    }
    // lastly, reverse this as well
    return dayjs(b).diff(dayjs(a))
}


If you want to compare Dates, you can convert them to epoch timestamps aka the time elapsed since January 1, 1970, UTC.
new Date().getTime()                               // 1717088172916, now's time
new Date("Thu, 2 January 1970 00:00:00").getTime() // 82800000

The lower the number, the older it is. Simplest way to sort them I think.
Here is a decent article on the subject.

Otherwise, Temporal API probably has some functions for that use-case. Or using any kind of date library should have such a feature too, but using a vanilla JS solution is always nice.

To filter on the array to convert into current time if null, then sort properly each timestamp
[42, "Thu, 2 January 1970 00:00:00", null, "Thu Jan 10 2023 19:23:55 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)"].map(date => {
  if(!date) { // if null
    return date = new Date().getTime() // set it to the current time
  }
  return new Date(date).getTime() // otherwise, convert the regular Date format into a timestamp
}).sort((a, b) => a - b)
// [42, 82800000, 1673371435000, 1717090069492]


I have added a update based off your response. However, I am still unsure how to get the null values to show up as the newest dates. If you can modify this to do that I will accept that answer because I am just struggling handling nulls to be honest at this point. Your approach is similar to what I used previously and deviated away trying to use only dayjs but ultimately you confirmed this is preferred.

@Qiuzman is it more explicit now?

I would not be able to intercept the items array in v-data-table to refilter it to do the custom sort function in the headers. So this approach would not work unfortunately. Claudes answer does work though. However, if you answer could do the comparison to check for null in the custom sort function that is what I was trying to achieve.

@Qiuzman is not sure to fully understand the custom sort or the issue here. Could make a three-part sort in the end. But since Claudes' answer works, use that I guess.

yea I apologize if my implementation is not making sense. Basically v-data-table header has the a ability to use a custom sort function and it willl apply this to the items data array. So really I cannot map anything in the header so this approach won't work. However, the getTime() approach is a clean non-dayjs approach to doing the comparison which I like I Just was struggling using this approach and accounting for the nulls. Does that make sense?
